# Is there a way to set rotation angles in VrVideoView from Google VR SDK?

Tags: android, google-cardboard, virtual-reality, google-vr

Having looked through all the documentation, I found a method that allows me to get the angle of view [VrWidgetView docs](https://developers.google.com/vr/android/reference/com/google/vr/sdk/widgets/common/VrWidgetView.html#getHeadRotation(float[]))

```
getHeadRotation(float[] yawAndPitch)
```

I need then to save it and apply at the next launch of video. Any way that it can be set programatically? Thanks in advance.

**Update**: Actually that method returns void. And I can't even see any difference when using it with different yaw and pitch values. So I need to know how to both get and set the rotation values.

**Update 2**: it is hilarious but only now I found out that the values are actually written to parameter instead of returning them. So I can get them, but don't see how I can apply them.

Comment: Can you upload an example for returned value from getHeadRotation(float[] yawAndPitch)?

Comment: Here we are using euler's formula  to get the angle ....i think so needed to check details

Comment: @omriherman the docs mislead me: "Provides yaw and pitch angles corresponding to where the user is looking." Then I assume no way to both get/set the angle?

Comment: Not through this method probably. but I think I have a solution, can you comment here an example for values you receive from this method in your application?

Comment: @omriherman this method returns void. And I can't tell the difference when using it with different float array values.

Comment: @omriherman if you have a working solution please post it.. And I will be very happy to upvote and mark as right answer

Comment: Haha of course I would, still workin on it ;)

Answer (score 0):

Not sure this can be considered a full answer, in case I can move it to a comment.

According to [this Google VR issue](https://github.com/googlevr/gvr-android-sdk/issues/586) such component will not be extended to give this type of *complex* features.

Google official suggestion is to look at the [Video360 Sample](https://developers.google.com/vr/android/samples/video360) as a starting point, and get your hand dirty.

Answer (score -1):

I think setting the head rotation in VR is a big no. It is very unnatural, it can cause nausea and provides a very bad experience.
If you need to set a starting rotation, you should probably go with rotating the world.

Comment: Imagine a device in VR hub standing in public. Everybody could use it, rotate and leave it with that angle. When the content updates it becomes recentered again, but there is wrong angle from that moment. That's why I need to set angles. This is also needed in moving things like cars etc